# Lizardfs or Musefs File lock for secondary user

Tags: centos, mount, filelock

I have 2 lizardfs servers and file system is shared to our LAN network . Shared folder is mounted to 3 of our windows systems . File copy , paste , delete , create all are working fine .

But , is there any option to lock a file if anyone is already using it ? Means he can read that file but no write permission . After the first person saves and exit from it the next person can use it , like that .
Is there any option for "mfsmount" to set these like permissions..?

If any other open source projects supporting these kind of features , please suggest your options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be a problem in previous lizardfs version but has been resolved a while back. That said, it is disabled by default.

To enable it, simply mount the lock like this:

```
mfsmount -o enablefilelocks /mnt/lizardfs
```

Documentation on mfsmount found here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/mfsmount.1.html

I'm talking linux here though... On windows, you should probably use the windows client. That is not opensource, but you can download a trial version https://lizardfs.com/download